# Angular: directive after expression

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Есть довольно обычная задача, с которой, как я думал и, наверное, до сих по думаю, легко справится AngularJS.

Есть латекс строка, выводимая в мной же определяемой директиве.

```
<latex>{{ task.taskMessage }}</latex>
```

Видимо, обработка директивы происходит раньше, чем исполнение выражения, поэтому я имею:

```
.directive("latex", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element[0].textContent); // '{{ task.taskMessage }}'
            // katex.render(element[0].textContent, element[0]);
        }
    };
})
```

Полазил на форумах и блогах, там есть похожие вопросы, решающиеся через data-content, $watcher и, не совем понял, с помощь ng-bind-html. Так как же все-таки правильно организовать именно мой вариант?

Comment: Если нужно получить значение `task.taskMessage` в директиве, то можно повесить $watch или $timeout и уже в них получить. Или выводить `{{task.taskMessage}}` через другую директиву приоритет, у которой будет выше.   

P.S. Я не особо силен в ангуларе, но, думаю, это может сработать.

Comment: @Алексей Данчин, а  можете написать, что вам нужно сделать? Если вам нужно вывести сложный html-код через переменную, то посмотрите [этот вопрос][1].

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/362250/

Comment: @MasterAlex, сначала должно сработать выражение и вставить текст, который является латекс кодировка математического выражения, а после директива latex должна отрендрить этот текст в правильную математическую формулу как в книжках.

Comment: katex рендрит текст в html разметку со своими стилями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось легко. Спасибо [[@whispeer](/users/8269/whispeer)](/users/8269/whispeer) и [[@MasterAlex](/users/22273/masteralex)](/users/22273/masteralex) за помощь. Мое работающее решение:

```
.directive("latex", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                katex.render(element[0].textContent, element[0]);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Работает, потому что `$timeout` срабатывает только после первого expression обхода.